# Не срабатывает код php через сервер (?) xampp

Tags: php, html

Добрый день, при создании html-страницы и вставки в нее php кода типа

```
<?php  phpinfo(); ?>
```

это так и открывается текстом. Что посоветуете?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменять расширение исполняемого файла с **.html** на **.php**

Еще могу посоветовать [OpenServer](http://open-server.ru/)

Отличная сборка, обновляется каждый месяц. Все заводится, подключается/отключается с пол пинка.

Comment: спасибо, установила openserver, localhost открыл, а страница с расширением .php все так же отображается. там просто код      <?php
phpinfo();
?>

теперь что делать?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/openserver/phpinfo.php    -  а вот это открылось. как сделать так, чтобы мои созданные в блокноте файлы php открывались?....

Comment: Вы убедитесь, что у вас php код вставлен не через WYSIWYG редактор. Используйте для редактирования Notepad++ или Sublime Text 3

Comment: да, использую notepad++

Comment: Лучше покажите исходный код документа.

Comment: <? php
phpinfo();
?> 
вот, это все,в браузере должна выйти документация, не так ли?

Comment: все, нашла папку localhost и перенесла этот файл туда. в браузере через localhost/test.php открылось! спасибо вам большое еще раз